# counting number of occurrences in nested list for duplicates

Tags: python, list

I have this list in python below which is a list of nested lists and want to count number of occurrences of a timestamp and print the count for each timestamp . How do I do that in python?

```
message= [['619833', 'Mon Jun  3 15:49:22 2019'], ['568391', 'Mon Jun  3 15:49:22 2019'], ['578934', 'Sat Jun  1 18:34:12 2019'], ['699425', 'Sat Jun  1 18:34:12 2019'], ['969231', 'Wed May 29 16:18:07 2019']]
```

Expected results:

```
['Mon Jun  3 15:49:22 2019', 2 ]
['Sat Jun  1 18:34:12 2019', 2 ]
```

Where 2 is the count.

Comment: So you have a list of tuples? not a list of lists?

Comment: Please fix your quote characters, and clarify whether these are tuples or lists. It would be best if you could just copy+paste real code.

Comment: So you also don't care about the initial number, just the timestamp part, right?

Comment: Still not real code, what are these smart-quotes?

Comment: Yes I edited the code it is a nested list and yes I don't care about initial number

Comment: This is not a nested list. It's 5 separate lists, one assigned to a variable, and all with incorrect quote characters. Please paste real code.

Comment: `Sat Jun  1 18:34:12 2019` is also appearing twice

Comment: And you expect a single tuple as output?

Comment: The way you pasted code is like a punishment for other readers who want to answer. It requires first converting everything to strings by removing the single quotes

Comment: @DSC yes but `‘` doesn't.

Comment: @DSC: Copy paste the list and see if you can run it. This is not single or double quotes

Comment: Try `[(k, sum(1 for i in message if k in i)) for k in set(m[1] for m in message)]`

Answer (score 2):

This is an edited version of @ArkistarvhKltzuonstev's response.

```
messages = [['619833', 'Mon Jun 3 15:49:22 2019'],['568391', 'Mon Jun 3 15:49:22 2019'],['578934', 'Sat Jun 1 18:34:12 2019'],['699425', 'Sat Jun 1 18:34:12 2019'],['969231', 'Wed May 29 16:18:07 2019']]

# Loop through each list
# Create a list called result which formats the data how you requested
result = [(k, sum(1 for i in messages if k in i)) for k in set(m[1] for m in messages)]
# Prints out that result list
print(result)
```

This is the quickest version to get you what you need.

Here is a more complete "program" with a reusable function:

```
# Loop through each list
# Create a list called result which formats the data how you requested
def print_count(arr):
    result = [(k, sum(1 for i in arr if k in i)) for k in set(m[1] for m in arr)]
    print(result)

# Create a main function
def main():
    # Declare a list (like the one OP provided)
    messages = [['619833', 'Mon Jun 3 15:49:22 2019'],['568391', 'Mon Jun 3 15:49:22 2019'],['578934', 'Sat Jun 1 18:34:12 2019'],['699425', 'Sat Jun 1 18:34:12 2019'],['969231', 'Wed May 29 16:18:07 2019']]
    # Call the function
    print_count(messages)

# Call the main function
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Counter` class from the `collections` interface. It'll give you the count for all the items you give it, and it can be initialized directly from a list. You can use a list comprehension to pick out the element you want from your nested list.

```
from collections import Counter

message = [['619833', 'Mon Jun  3 15:49:22 2019'],
['568391', 'Mon Jun  3 15:49:22 2019'],
['578934', 'Sat Jun  1 18:34:12 2019'],
['699425', 'Sat Jun  1 18:34:12 2019'],
['969231', 'Wed May 29 16:18:07 2019']]

print(Counter([x[1] for x in message]))
```

Which gives you the following output:

```
Counter({'Mon Jun  3 15:49:22 2019': 2, 'Sat Jun  1 18:34:12 2019': 2, 'Wed May 29 16:18:07 2019': 1})
```

You can use the `most_common` method on the counter to get the structure you've mentioned in your question:

```
>>> print(c.most_common())
[('Mon Jun  3 15:49:22 2019', 2), ('Sat Jun  1 18:34:12 2019', 2), ('Wed May 29 16:18:07 2019', 1)]
```